# AutoDeploy a WAR file found in a subfolder of appBase

Tags: tomcat, war, autodeploy

I have a third party web application which I would like to deploy to a Tomcat 5.0 server via an installer. AutoDeploy is set to true. However, the application consists of more than one WAR file.

If I put the WARs under /webapps directly, they work like a charm. However, I would like to expand them under /webapps/myapp/..and here the expanded WAR directory... This way they do not get AutoDeployed. Can somebody suggest what I need to configure for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html#Automatic%20Application%20Deployment) page suggests, you can place two XML files into `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/[engine_name]/[host_name]` directory (e.g. `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost`) each defining a [Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) for one of two WARs.

First one (e.g. app1context.xml):

```
<Context path="/myapp/app1" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/myapp/app1war">

</Context>
```

And the second one (e.g. app2context.xml):

```
<Context path="/myapp/app2" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/myapp/app2war">

</Context>
```

Answer (score 10):

**Knowing the question is years old, now answering for Tomcat 8.5 here.**

You can change the name of your .war like this: `myapp#app1.war`

After you place this .war in `webapps`, Tomcat to deploy your application in `webapps/myapp/app1`.