# Tomcat 7: Deploy a war file inside sub directory of webapp

Tags: java, tomcat7

If we place a `war` file inside `webapps` folder of tomcat then it deploys it when we start the server, but it is not the case when we place the `war` file inside a sub folder of `webapps`.
Is there any way by which we can achieve this deployment process within sub directory of `webapps`?

Comment: [Please use Context for deploy two sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891769/how-to-load-large-sql-script-against-oracle-database-using-jdbc)

Comment: @ĐứcTrầnTrung, link shared redirecting me to thread `how-to-load-large-sql-script-against-oracle-database-using-jdbc`. is it the same thread you wanted to share?

Comment: Sorry it's not correct, please take a look at [AutoDeploy a WAR file found in a subfolder of appBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523598/autodeploy-a-war-file-found-in-a-subfolder-of-appbase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the war deployment path(application base directory) in `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`.

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps\your_directory"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Answer (score 4):

While using autodeploy, if you want your application to be accessed at `server.com/path/app`, you can achieve this by naming your war file to "`path#app.war`" before placing it into webapps directory.
During autodeploy, a directory named "`path#app`" will be created under "`${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/`" and your application will be accessible at the desired URL path.

You can also choose to leave it where it is and instruct the reverse proxy in front of Tomcat to do the relocation, using `ProxyPass /path/app http://tomcat-server/app
ProxyPassReverse /path/app http://tomcat-server/app` rules if the reverse proxy is Apache HTTPD. ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse reference is available [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).